# Getting neighborhood from google maps or check if address is in neighborhood location

Tags: javascript, php, google-maps-api-3, google-geocoder

I need to check if address is inside neighborhood using google geocode API, or get neighborhood by street address from google places API.

I'm trying to get neighborhood by street name and number in Latvia, Riga.

If request to geocoding API is made to get coordinates and all available data via this request:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=A+Deglava+iela+104&components=country:LV|postal_code:LV-1082

google does not return neighborhood address component, however if I manually use google maps to search for neighborhood name in google maps, it shows that neighborhood

[image]

It could be that google does not support neighborhood lookup by street name, but then how could I check that my street name and number is in location inside or outside of neighborhood.

Problem is that I can get viewport of that neighborhood, but google gives rectangle and that rectangle would cross with other neighborhoods

Example coordinates of "Purvciems" neighborhood
{
    "northeast": {
        "lat": 56.96616400000001,
        "lng": 24.2093959
    },
    "southwest": {
        "lat": 56.94633899999999,
        "lng": 24.1568988
    }
}

Also I have searched for containsLocation()

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/poly-containsLocation

But it would return results only by your custom polygon.